# How do I add a TXT or A record using Unbound?

Tags: command-line, server, 18.04, dns, bind

I am currently following [this](https://www.dreamvps.com/tutorials/install-and-integrate-rspamd/#install-unbound) tutorial. The author says we can add a TXT record on the local DNS resolver. But can I please know how do I do that?

How do I add a TXT or A record on the local server (127.0.0.1) using `unbound`?

> System - Ubuntu 18.04 (AWS EC2 Instance).

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Unbound documentation](https://unbound.docs.nlnetlabs.nl/en/latest/manpages/unbound.conf.html#term-local-data-resource-record-string), you can add a TXT record as local data.

An example of this: (adding both an A and a TXT record for a subdomain)

```
local-zone: "somedomain.country." static
local-data: "sub1.somedomain.country. IN A 127.0.0.1"
local-data: 'sub1.somedomain.country. IN TXT "f1=this is a TXT record; f2=second part of TXT record"'
```

Please note that the outer quotes when adding a TXT record should be single quotes, since the TXT records itself is in double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

"The author says we can add a TXT record on the local DNS resolver." The author does not say that.

`unbound` is a recursive validating resolver. Its purpose is just to resolve names, by querying other nameservers. It has no data itself on names, just what it retrieves.

Adding a `TXT` record needs to happen on the **authoritative** nameservers for the zone, which by definition can not be `unbound`.

So you need to find out the nameservers for the zone where you want to add a `TXT` record for DKIM purposes, and change the zonefile there. Probably through some website or API offered by the provider currently managing your authoritative nameservers.

Comment: Unbound can manage local DNS zones, with all normal records. Voted as "not an answer", since it's largely incorrect.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Yes it can technically, but in practice it is far better to clearly separate recursive and authoritative services. Mixing the two only yiels to problems later, and as such not everything you can do you should do. I stand by the point that it is better to use `unbound` solely for what it is, a recursive nameserver. It also help people to clear the widespread confusion between authoritative and recursive nameservers.

Comment: I largely agree with you on a philosophical level. However, I'd say this very much depends on the usecase for each user. In my homelab (and for many others as well), it's probably not an issue to run local zones with Unbound. If you're running a datacenter, it might be another matter. But since the question asked how to do this, and it's indeed possible (and very easy to do) with Unbound, I still feel your answer somewhat misses the essence of the question.

Answer (score -1):

In unbound configuration there is option to use 'local-zone' and 'local-data' sections.
In server: section you specify something along the lines of:

```
    local-zone: "somedomain.country." redirect
    local-data: "d1.somedomain.country. IN A <IP redacted>"
    local-data: 'somedomain.country. TXT "txt record data "'
```

Note the use of double quotes for TXT record itself and single quotes for local-data parameter

For more - see [Unbound documentation](https://unbound.docs.nlnetlabs.nl/en/latest/manpages/unbound.conf.html#term-local-data-resource-record-string).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).